# How do i translate this to "simpler" JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, titanium

Since i'm working with Titanium i realzed that its current JavaScript Interpreter doesn't accept specific coding-styles.

So for for-loops and if-statements i have to have braces, even though i only want to span one line. Furthermore there is more i have to change if i want to use a Javascript Library like underscore.js. This is what Titanium doesn't want to see:

```
if (!(result = result && iterator.call(context, value, index, list))) {_.breakLoop();}

if (nativeSome && obj.some === nativeSome) {return obj.some(iterator, context);}

var computed = iterator ? iterator.call(context, value, index, list) : value;

computed >= result.computed && (result = {value : value, computed : computed});
```

Can i use a simpler syntax to describe the logic behind those lines of code?

Comment: Have you tried using a code beautifier? You could also run your code through JSLint, but it might make you cry...

Comment: looks promising, im going to try some of these out

Answer (score 0):

It looks concise but `result = result` ? Why is that? other than that your syntax looks simple. Also your code looks verbose and may be easily understandable than a more concise form.

Comment: He's using the `&&` operator as a "guard".

Comment: i forgot to mention that it is not my code, i'm trying to make the "underscore.js" library work in Appcelerator Titamium.


You can google it to take a look at the code